# Use dpl on GitHub Actions

Tags: travis-ci, github-actions, dpl

I was used with dpl on gitlab ci. Our repo was using a specific version and the code was like that:

```
prod_deploy_api_developer:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "prod_deploy_api running"
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -yqq ruby ruby-dev --silent
    - gem install dpl -v 1.8.47
    - cd ./api
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=myapp --api-key=mycrazykey --skip-cleanup
```

Now we migrated that codebase to GitHub, and I didn't found a **GitHub Action** ready to run.

Answer (score 1):

I just published [Dpl Github Action](https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/github-dpl-action).

It's a very simple implementation, and I just added **heroku** as provider, because is the one I needed to deploy my project like used to do on GitLab.

A use example with heroku:

### Example

```
- name: Dpl to heroku
  uses: tiagogouvea/github-dpl-action@master
  with:
    provider: 'heroku'
    app: 'your-heroku-app-name'
    api-key: 'your-66a593c465c7ec9-heroku-api-key'
```